# How to find the table name and path of my Access linked table

Tags: ms-access

I have a PC where someone made a linked table in MS Access pointing to a MySQL table on the server.

The linked table is working and I can call query on it but I want to know the "path" and the real name of this linked table on the server: my goal is to query directly the database on the server with DataGrip without using the linked table on Access.

I logged in the server with my DataGrip but i can't find the data I want on its schema and tables, that's why i need to know the "path" pointed by the linked table in Access.
Thank you guys!

I connected to the original MySQL database on the server with DataGrip but I don't know where to find the data shown in the Access linked table

Comment: Right-click the table in the Navigation pane. Select _Manage linkedt tables_.

Comment: i did it but that's what i see: [link] (https://ibb.co/bg2q2fn)

Comment: Then look up that DSN on your machine - the ODBC Manager. But all this is OT here at SO where code is supposed to be discussed.

Comment: In the Immediate Window: `?CurrentDb.TableDefs("link name here").Connect` also `.SourceTableName` in place of .Connect.